# React Chart JS 2: fill in with custom style for the remaining gap for the bar chart

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I am building a React JS application. In my application, I need to display data in Bar chart. I am using this library, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2. Now, I have a chart like this.

[image]

This is the code for that

```
const colorCode = '#1478BD';
const state = {
  data: {
    labels: ['J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D'],
    datasets: [
      {
        fill: true,
        label: null,
        backgroundColor: colorCode,
        borderColor: colorCode,
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 40, 56]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        },
        beginAtZero: false,
        ticks: {
          color: colorCode,
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          color: colorCode,
        }
      }
    },
  }
}


<Bar
            type={"bar"}
            height={170}
            data={state.data}
            options={state.options}
          />
```

What I want to do is that I also want to add some background so that I can customing the styling for the remaining gap for each bar. Something like this.

[image]

Ass you can see, we can see the background when the bar is not filling the entire height. How can I do that? Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `beforeDraw` plugin for this

```
const plugins = [
  {
    beforeDraw: function (chart) {
      if (chart.chartArea) {
        var ctx = chart.ctx;
        var chartArea = chart.chartArea;
        var barArray = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data;

        ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE";

        for (let i = 0; i < barArray.length; i++) {
          const { x, width } = barArray[i];

          ctx.fillRect(
            x - width / 2,
            chartArea.top,
            width,
            chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
];


<Bar
  type={"bar"}
  height={170}
  data={state.data}
  options={state.options}
  plugins={plugins}
/>
```